# Android: issue adding video file to the media content provider

Tags: android, file, video, media, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to add a video file to the media content provider. When I do so, the video is inserted but something is wrong with its file path. The video shows up in Gallery but if you try to play it from gallery it gives an error "cannot play content". The file is a copy of a file that was already in the gallery and the original file plays just fine.

That is:

- call an intent to record a video from the Camera (which will already insert it into the media content provider
- copy the video file into a new path (this works)
- try to insert the copied file (the destination file) into the media content provider as well

As mentioned, the video shows up in gallery (twice: the original video in the DCIM folder plus the copied video) but the copy can't be played.

Here's the code. I din't write it by myself, it is actually from the ODK Collect application, and the original ODK Collect application (prior to my modification) doesn't work either:

```
        //binaryuri comes from recording a video with the Camera component as an intent
        String binaryPath = getPathFromUri((Uri) binaryuri);
        String extension = binaryPath.substring(binaryPath.lastIndexOf("."));
        String destVideoPath = mInstanceFolder + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + extension;

        File source = new File(binaryPath);
        File newVideo = new File(destVideoPath);
        //this simply copies the file into a new location, and it works fine:
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, newVideo); 

        if (newVideo.exists()) {
            // Add the copy to the content provier
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues(6);
            values.put(Video.Media.TITLE, newVideo.getName());
            values.put(Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, newVideo.getName());
            values.put(Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
            values.put(Video.Media.DATA, newVideo.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.d(t,"Inserting VIDEO: data: "+values.getAsString(Video.Media.DATA));
            Uri VideoURI =
                getContext().getContentResolver().insert(Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            Log.i(t, "Inserting VIDEO returned uri = " + VideoURI.toString());

            // ** THIS PART I ADDED FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES ONLY **

            // check: (for debug only)
            Cursor c=getContext().getContentResolver().query(VideoURI, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                Log.i(t,"The data path of the inserted video is "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Video.Media.DATA)));
            }
            // check: (for debug only)
            c=getContext().getContentResolver().query(Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null,Video.Media.DATA +" = '"+newVideo.getAbsolutePath()+"'", null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                Log.d(t,"Double checked: video exists in media content provider");
            }
            else {
                Log.d(t,"Can't find the newly inserted video by file path");
            }


        } else {
            Log.e(t, "Inserting Video file FAILED");
        }
```

This produces the following output in the log:

> 02-18 18:14:54.888 D/MediaWidget(12752): Inserting VIDEO: data:
>   /mnt/sdcard/megafone/instances/Matteo2 New
>   York_2012-02-18_18-14-37/1329585294726.3gp 02-18 18:14:54.908
>   I/MediaWidget(12752): Inserting VIDEO returned uri =
>   content://media/external/video/media/5 02-18 18:14:54.918
>   I/MediaWidget(12752): The data path of the inserted video is
>   /mnt/sdcard/megafone/instances/Matteo2 New
>   York_2012-02-18_18-14-37/1329585294726.3gp 02-18 18:14:54.928
>   D/MediaWidget(12752): Can't find the newly inserted video by file path

This is driving me crazy. Just after inserting the file I query the content provider and check its file path and it is actually the same value I gave it. However immediately after, I look for an item in the data base with that value for the DATA field and the video is not found (and the query is OK: i do the same with images and it works).

Any idea on why the inserted video is corrupted and how to fix this?